# no email send android

Tags: android, eclipse, gmail

I want when I click on button an email will be send automatically to the user.

I followed this : Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

and here is my code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570957/sending-email-without-user-notice

No crashes or errors, but no email was sent!

Can someone please solve it for me ?

thank you

GmailSender class:

```
package com.example.tesst;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com",imagePath;   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   

static 
{   
    Security.addProvider(new com.example.tesst.JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GmailSender(String user, String password,String imagePath) {   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   
    this.imagePath=imagePath;
    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   


    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}   

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{


         Transport transport = session.getTransport();  

         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
         message.setSubject(subject);  
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));  
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));  

         //  
         // This HTML mail have to 2 part, the BODY and the embedded image  
         //  
         MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");  

         // first part  (the html)  
         BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
         String htmlText = "<H1>"+body+"</H1>";  
         messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");  

         // add it  
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

         // second part (the image)  
      //   messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
     //    DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(imagePath);  
     //    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));  
     //    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID",imagePath);  

         // add it  
       //  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

         // put everything together  
         message.setContent(multipart);  

         transport.connect();  
         transport.sendMessage(message,message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));  
         transport.close();  
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("", "FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION "+e.getMessage());
    }
}   

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
}   
}
```

JSSEProvider  class

```
   package com.example.tesst;


   import java.security.AccessController;

   import java.security.Provider;


   public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}


   }
```

MainActivity  class

```
 package com.example.tesst;


 import android.os.Bundle;

 import android.app.Activity;

 import android.util.Log;

 import android.view.Menu;

 import android.view.View;

 import android.widget.Button;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public Button send;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    send=(Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {   
                   GmailSender sender = new GmailSender("mobilibksu@gmail.com", "12345","");
                   sender.sendMail("test","bla bla blaaaa","lamachanz@gmail.com","lamachanz@gmail.com");   
                } 
             catch (Exception e) 
               {   
                   Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
               }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


 }
```

Comment: Please do not ask twice. Also I encourage you to get familiar with what is considered [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO to keep the good times rolling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending email without user notice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570957/sending-email-without-user-notice)

Answer (score 0):

in activity write

```
try {   
                   GmailSender sender = new GmailSender("gmailusername", "gmailpassword","");
                   sender.sendMail("Registration to Model Apps:","username="+username+"\n password="+password,"gmailusername","gmailusername");   
                } 
             catch (Exception e) 
               {   
                   Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
               }



and create class  GmailSender

package com.example.ur;//write ur pakage

import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com",imagePath;   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static 
    {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.example.model.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GmailSender(String user, String password,String imagePath) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   
        this.imagePath=imagePath;
        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   


        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{


             Transport transport = session.getTransport();  

             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
             message.setSubject(subject);  
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));  
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));  

             //  
             // This HTML mail have to 2 part, the BODY and the embedded image  
             //  
             MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");  

             // first part  (the html)  
             BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
             String htmlText = "<H1>"+body+"</H1>";  
             messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");  

             // add it  
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

             // second part (the image)  
          //   messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
         //    DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(imagePath);  
         //    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));  
         //    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID",imagePath);  

             // add it  
           //  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

             // put everything together  
             message.setContent(multipart);  

             transport.connect();  
             transport.sendMessage(message,message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));  
             transport.close();  
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("", "FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

and create other class JSSEProvider

```
    package com.example.model;


    import java.security.AccessController;
    import java.security.Provider;

    public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

        public JSSEProvider() {
            super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
            AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
                public Void run() {
                    put("SSLContext.TLS",
                            "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                    put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                    put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                            "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                    put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                            "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }

 }
```

import library -  activation.jar
     additionnal.jar
      mail.jar

Comment: i have already done this, check this please  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570957/sending-email-without-user-notice

Comment: here : 'sender.sendMail("Registration to Model Apps:","username="+username+"\n password="+password,"gmailusername","gmailusername");' what do i do with the username and password ? change them to mine ?

Comment: syntax is like that sender.sendMail(subject,body,sender,reciever);  ok  then you use   sender.sendMail(emai subject,body,username,username);

Comment: yes i just realize that thanks, but when i run it i have the same problem nothing will be sent ! why ? please help me

Comment: u add jar file in lib

Comment: yes i did :( is there specific syntacx to write the email and passworrd ? or i just write them email:"lama@gmail.com" pass""*****" ?

Comment: post ur code  sender.sendMail(emai subject,body,username,username);

Comment: sender.sendMail("test","bla bla blaaaaaa","mobilibksu@gmail.com","lamachanz@gmail.com");

Comment: try this  sender.sendMail("test","bla bla blaaaaaa","mobilibksu@gmail.com","mobilibksu@gmail.com");

Comment: sorry use that sender.sendMail("test","bla bla blaaaaaa","lamachanz@gmail.com","lamachanz@gmail.com");

Comment: hey check that or not?

Comment: i am checking it .. :)

Comment: both place use reciver emailid ok

Comment: did not work tooo :'( !! can i send it email to see it please ?

Comment: i use that   GmailSender sender = new GmailSender("myemaiid", "mypassword","");
                sender.sendMail("subjectdata","mydata",reciverid,reciverid);

Comment: 12-14 03:12:09.791: E/(920): FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION null
.... i have this error came in the logcat when i clcik on the button

Comment: please help me i really need this :(